# Is that possible to have a DBMS with different data in databases nodes?

Tags: sql-server, database

We're looking for the best setup to distribute databases for large databases. We would like to have more databases in multiple computers and to have every database tables which we're using in the particular part of the globe, then we would like to have a common table set which we would like to synchronize between the database nodes. We would like to extend a large platform but it's very hard to implement the functionality which will choose which connection string we need to use. That's why we started to have research on this and seems that DBMS may have this functionality.

Can you suggest some material/documentation/tutorial we could use? We're using SQL server.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not you create database in cloud like Azure and enable geo redundant and zone redundant which will take care of your requirement instead you doing the same?